# Developing native dapps with Go

Tags: dapps, golang

so I was looking around for a decent up-to-date tutorial to start developing native dapps (C++ or GO doesn't really matter), but I can't seem to find a concise tutorial rather than [this one](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native-DApps:-Go-bindings-to-Ethereum-contracts). Can someone give me a link where I can start? Also I'd have to clarify that I'm looking to implement a local database for the dapp that is why I don't want to use the web3 library, which tbh looks way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great starting point is the free little book **[Ethereum development with Go](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book)**. It provides many examples for getting up and running on creating a dapp using Golang.